# Having an issue with similar() function saying there are floats present when there shouldn't be any

Tags: python, typeerror, translation, similarity

Basically I'm trying to build a translation program for a project, and I've almost finished it. I'm having trouble with one language (Nahuatl). The other three, English, Spanish, and Huasteca work fine, but whenever I use Nahuatl I get this error: TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len().

I'm confused, as both the inputs for the similar() function are strings, and the same code works fine. I'll paste all the code below if it'll help.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
def similar(a , b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
#%%
englishdic = pd.read_csv('englishdic.csv', sep = ',', encoding = 'latin-1')
spanishdic = pd.read_csv('spanishdic.csv', sep = ',', encoding = 'latin-1')
huastecadic = pd.read_csv('huastecadic.csv', sep = ',', encoding = 'latin-1')
nahuatldic = pd.read_csv('nahuatldic.csv', sep = ',', encoding = 'latin-1')

#%%
englishterms = englishdic.iloc[:, : -1]
englishdefs = englishdic.iloc[:, -1]
spanishterms = spanishdic.iloc[:, : -1]
spanishdefs = spanishdic.iloc[:, -1]
huastecaterms = huastecadic.iloc[:, : -1]
huastecadefs = huastecadic.iloc[:, -1]
nahuatlterms = nahuatldic.iloc[:, : -1]
nahuatldefs = nahuatldic.iloc[:, -1]
#%%
InLang = input("Enter the language you would like to translate from: \n")
OutLang = input("Enter the language you would like to translate to: \n")
InputWord = input("Enter the word you would like to translate: \n")
if InLang == "English":
    Iterms = englishterms
    Idefs = englishdefs
if InLang == "Spanish":
    Iterms = spanishterms
    Idefs = spanishdefs
if InLang == "Huasteca":
    Iterms = huastecaterms
    Idefs = huastecadefs
if InLang == "Nahuatl":
    Iterms = nahuatlterms
    Idefs = nahuatldefs
if OutLang == "English":
    Odefs = englishdefs
    Oterms = englishterms
if OutLang == "Spanish":
    Odefs = spanishdefs
    Oterms = spanishterms
if OutLang == "Huasteca":
    Oterms = huastecaterms
    Odefs = huastecadefs
if OutLang == "Nahuatl":
    Odefs = nahuatldefs
    Oterms = nahuatlterms

#print(Iterms)
termresults = []
tempterms = []
for ind in Iterms.index:
    tempterms.append(Iterms['Term'][ind])
#print(tempterms)
print("Entered: " + InputWord)
for temp in tempterms:
    tempresult = similar(temp, InputWord)
    termresults.append(tempresult)
#print(termresults)
besttermprob = np.argmax(termresults)
#print(besttermprob)
testdef = Idefs[besttermprob]
print(testdef)
defresults = []
tempdefs = []
for temp in Odefs:
    tempdefs.append(temp)
for temp in tempdefs:
    tempresult = similar(temp, testdef) <----
    defresults.append(tempresult)
#print(defresults)
bestdefprob = np.argmax(defresults)
print('Result: ' + Oterms.iloc[bestdefprob])
```

The arrow is where the IDE says the error is, but both temp and testdef are strings. If anyone knows what's going on, please let me know. Thanks in advance.